# Get joomla component current page title outside of component

Tags: joomla

i am using joomla 2.5 and i want to put current component page title outside of component. For example, i need to get joomshopping component current page title and put it anywhere in template.

I found a solution:

```
<?php $mydoc =& JFactory::getDocument();$mytitle = $mydoc->getTitle();echo $mytitle; 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
<?php $mydoc =& JFactory::getDocument(); $mytitle = $mydoc->getTitle(); echo $mytitle; ?>
```

Comment: This gets the page title, including the prefix if one has been configured.

Answer (score 0):

I Assume you already have created menu item for that component. Within the template it is simply:

```
<?php echo $this->title; ?>
```

Comment: unfortunately it is not working :( i looked at joomshopping component template file, to get category name: <?php print $this->category->name?> but when i put this code outside of component it is not working.

Comment: Of course this will not work, because you want to display product category, not component page title like you mentioned above. I would suggest you to create a custom module which populates product category name from the database.

Comment: it should vary, when current page is component category, than i get category name and when i go deeper to product page i get product title. Maybe someone could help me with this?